# Can anyone outline the theory of plane wave Born approximation for direct nuclear reactions in detail?

Tags: waves, nuclear-physics, approximations

1. Can anyone outline the theory of plane wave [Born approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_approximation) for direct nuclear reactions in detail?
2. Also What are the modification introduced in the distorted wave Born approximation?

I was unable to find the right material/books/web resources on this.

Comment: The DWIA approximation adds optical models to the incoming and outgoing waves. In my dissertation I cited Frullani and Mourgey (*Adv. Nucl. Phys.14:1--285, 1984*) and de Forest (*Annals of Phys. 45:365--403, 1995*).